# Deleting all files in folders except for defined name in list with Python

Tags: python

I have some folders with many files inside (they filename has all the same pattern).
For example 0_ABC, 1_ABC, ..., N_ABC

I have created a list with filenames I want to keep

`filename = ['65_ABC', '90_ABC', etc.]`

Now I want to write a function which iterates through all files within a folder and delete everything except those names which are in the list.

How can I achieve that?

I found out how to delete files with this function but not sure what to insert in `glob()`

```
import glob, os
for f in glob.glob():
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Add an condition `if f not in filename:` then you know it isn't in your keep list and you can delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` module:

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path('your/dirpath')
filenames = ['65_ABC', '90_ABC', 'etc.']

for path in root.iterdir():
    if path.name not in filenames:
        path.unlink()
```

This solution assumes that tour root dir contains only files. Otherwise, you can use `Path.glob(pattern)` to walk recursively into your directory (you should maybe also check if your path is file or dir path, with `Path.is_dir()` and `Path.is_file()`functions).

See [pathlib doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to further help